# NetBeans plugin - open file at specific line and column

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I would like to open file specified by its path in NetBeans editor at specific line and row.
I would like the same functionality as is when some Java/C/C++ or any other programming language prints an Exception.
As far as I went for now:

1. Write Exception in console
2. By using OutputListener resolve what should be printed as hypertext
3. OutputListener.outputLineAction that defines what to do when clicked on hypertext
4. ---HERE I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO---

An example of error message I need to resolve:

`E ERRORCODE: error definition; line=2; column=30; source='file:/C:/...'`

How can I open file in my plugin in text editor and point to specific line and column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqOpenFileAtLine

`LineCookie` - see https://forums.netbeans.org/topic59253.html

or

`NbDocument#openDocument()` - see http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-text/org/openide/text/NbDocument.html#openDocument(org.openide.util.Lookup.Provider, int, int, org.openide.text.Line.ShowOpenType, org.openide.text.Line.ShowVisibilityType)

---

Example using `LineCookie`

```
    FileObject fo = null;
    LineCookie lc = DataObject.find(fo).getLookup().lookup(LineCookie.class);
    int lineNumber=42;
    int colNumber=43;
    Line line = lc.getLineSet().getOriginal(lineNumber);
    line.show(Line.ShowOpenType.OPEN, Line.ShowVisibilityType.FRONT, colNumber);
```

More examples at

- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/org_openide_cookies_linecookie
- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/jump_to_declaration_for_freemarker

Comment: I belive the NbDocument.openDocument might be the right way. However I  really dont know how to use that Lookup and Lookup.provider.
As the lookup i use `Lookup lookup = Lookups.forPath(path_ref);` where path_ref is String path to the file I would like to open
and then the Lookup.Provider uses this lookup. The problem is, that the openDocument() method doesnt return true (and doesnt show anything).

Comment: See the code sample above. LineCookie should do the job.

Comment: It took a while to get back to my computer, but I must thank you! The FileObject can be obtained by `File f = new File(path_ref);
                FileObject fo = FileUtil.toFileObject(f);` The rest is the same. Thank you very much!